# External Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a form and am looking to create a external javascript to validate my form. i've had a look around the web and seen a few examples but I'm still not sure if I'm on the right track. Im trying to validate that all fields have been filled in correctly and meet certain criteria and if they don't a message will pop up telling them whats wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my form:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/exjava/javascript.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form name="userForm" method="post">
 Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" size="50" />
 <br /><br />
 Address: <input type= "text" name="Address" size="30"/>
 <br/><br/>
 Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode" size="4"/>
 <br><br/>
 Email: <input type="text" name="email" required="required"/>
 <br><br/>
 Credit Card Details:
 <>br><br/>
 <select name="Card Type">
 <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
 <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
 <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
 </select>
 <br><br/>
 <select name="Month">
 <option value="1">January</option>
 <option value="2">Febuary</option>
 <option value="3">March</option>
 <option value="4">April</option>
 <option value="5">May</option>
 <option value="6">June</option>
 <option value="7">July</option>
 <option value="8">August</option>
 <option value="9">September</option>
 <option value="10">October</option>
 <option value="11">November</option>
 <option value="12">December</option>
 </select>  
 <br><br/>
 <Select name="Year">
 <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
 <option value="2016">2016</option>
 <option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
 <option value="2019">2019</option>
 <option value="2020">2020</option>
 <option value="2021">2021</option>
 <option value="2022">2022</option>
 <option value="2023">2023</option>
 <option value="2024">2024</option>
 <br><br/>
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /> 
 <br><br/>
 <input type="reset" name="Reset" Value="Reset Form">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is my external java script so far:

```
  <script style="text/javascript">
  function formValidation()  
  {    
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;  
   var add = document.getElementById("address").value;    
  var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;  
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var creditcard = document.getElementById("creditcard").value;     
  {  
  if(name=="")  
    { 
    document.getElementById("name error").innerHTML="Please Enter Name"
    flag=false;
     } 
   if(alphanumeric(add))    
   {  
   if(allnumeric(postcode,4))  
    {  
    if(ValidateEmail(email,@,.))
    {
    if(allnumeric(creditcard,16))       
    return false;  
    </script>
```

Comment: What are you asking in particular? Are you just wanting someone to review your code for errors? Or do you have a specific question?

Comment: For starters, your JavaScript code seems incomplete.  You open a lot of curly braces without ever closing them.  (You even open an extra one for no particular reason.)  You also don't seem to be calling your function anywhere.  You also have `script` tags in your JavaScript file, which aren't necessary or correct.  And do you define those other functions that you're calling within your JavaScript anywhere?

Comment: Yes i know my javascript is incomplete. It is what i have done so far. I want to know if what i have done in my javascript so far is correct? As in the structure of it I guess because I have seen a few examples that look different to mine.

Comment: How would I go about validating my form? Is it similar to what I have done so far? As I think I might be on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add ID to your inputs

```
<form name="userForm" method="post">
 Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="firstname" size="50" />
 <br /><br />
 Address: <input type= "text" id="address" name="Address" size="30"/>
 <br/><br/>
 Postcode: <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" size="4"/>
 <br><br/>
 Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required"/>
 <br><br/>
 Credit Card Details:
 <br><br/>
 <select name="Card Type" id="creditcard">
 <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
 <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
 <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
 </select>
 <br><br/>
 <select name="Month">
 <option value="1">January</option>
 <option value="2">Febuary</option>
 <option value="3">March</option>
 <option value="4">April</option>
 <option value="5">May</option>
 <option value="6">June</option>
 <option value="7">July</option>
 <option value="8">August</option>
 <option value="9">September</option>
 <option value="10">October</option>
 <option value="11">November</option>
 <option value="12">December</option>
 </select>  
 <br><br/>
 <Select name="Year">
 <option value="2014">2014</option>
 <option value="2015">2015</option>
 <option value="2016">2016</option>
 <option value="2017">2017</option>
 <option value="2018">2018</option>
 <option value="2019">2019</option>
 <option value="2020">2020</option>
 <option value="2021">2021</option>
 <option value="2022">2022</option>
 <option value="2023">2023</option>
 <option value="2024">2024</option>
 <br><br/>
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /> 
 <br><br/>
 <input type="reset" name="Reset" Value="Reset Form">
 </form>
```

Comment: As in like <Select name="Year" id="year">? Is that what I need for all of them?

Comment: @user3444694, yes i mentioned the ones the you used in the javascript :)